# The performance of an InheritedWidget

Tags: flutter

Does the InheritedWidget pass the data to its children with the build walkthrough which is [explained in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUiVkDpikDI&t=931s)? Or how does it work? And how good is the performance?
Because I realised that it's only possible to get information from the InheritedWidget in the build method and when the dependencies are changing.

Comment: For performance questions it's always a good idea to do your own benchmarks to get numbers that match your actual use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This video talks about something totally unrelated. It's about how layout is computed.

`InheritedWidget` is quite performant to say the least. As stated in the documentation of [`inheritFromWidgetOfExtactType`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/inheritFromWidgetOfExactType.html) :

> Calling this method is O(1) with a small constant factor

This means that any widget has a **direct** access to any `InheritedWidget`.

In comparison, the equivalent with `State` : [`ancestorStateOfType`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/ancestorStateOfType.html) is O(N).
As it has to walk through the whole tree to find the desired `State` instance.

---

Under the hood, `InheritedWidget` are represented somewhere with `Map<Type, InheritedElement>`

Then, when calling `inheritFromWidgetOfExactType`, accessing the desired value is as simple as `map[type]`.

Comment: Thank you Remi. :) I knew that it was unrelated it was just a guess how it could work.